# How can I force a child to only inherit the position of its parent while ignoring its parents rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a simple mechanic where I control the rotation of an object that is childed to a parent.

Imagine a pot of water on the shoulder of a person. When the person jumps, the pot also changes position since it is a child. But I dont want to inherit the parent rotation. As I want to control the rotation of this child via script/gyroscope.

I know that a common solution to this would be to freeze the rotation in script within `LateUpdate()`:

```
Vector3 InitPos;

void Start () 
{
    InitRot = transform.rotation;
}

void LateUpdate () 
{
   transform.rotation = InitRot;      
}
```

This would work, if I did not intend on controlling the rotation separately. Like mentioned above, I want to control the rotation of the child via touch or gyroscope. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Id argue the pot should never be part of the human...  the problem you have is the child is not aware of the rotation of the parent.. because it moves as one. you would need to either tell the parent to reset the child (not great idea) or have the child check for parental rotation change and then counter it.. adding its own rotation is the same as then any normal rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detach the child object from parent object, then make an empty gameobject under the parent object which will be target object, then with a basic follow script just follow the empty target object like

```
void Update()
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, following.transform.position,followSpeed);
```

or directly

```
 void Update()
    transform.position = following.transform.position
```